# How to switch services in TestServer using WebApplicationFactory?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, xunit

I'm using custom WebApplication factory

```cs
public class CustomWebApplicationFactory<TStartup> : WebApplicationFactory<TStartup> where TStartup: class {
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder) {
        builder.ConfigureServices(services => {
            // Create a new service provider.
            var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
                .AddEntityFrameworkInMemoryDatabase()
                .BuildServiceProvider();

            services.AddDbContext<GrabGoContext>(options => {
                options.UseInMemoryDatabase("GrabGoDb");
                options.UseInternalServiceProvider(serviceProvider);
            });

            services.AddSingleton<TestEmailServer>();
            services.AddScoped<IEmailProvider, TestEmailProvider>(); // <- HERE
        });
        base.ConfigureWebHost(builder);
    }
```

I want to switch my default `IEmailProvider` service called `DefaultEmailProvider` to my special `TestEmailProvider`, but the problem is that the method `ConfigureWebHost` is executed before `Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)`, so my service `DefaultEmailProvider` is set after `TestEmailProvider`. Therefore in my `ClientController` service `DeafultEmailProvider` is used instead of test service.

My question is:

How can I switch service `DefaultEmailProvider` with my `TestEmailProvider` using WebApplicationFactory?

@Update

Ok, I've managed to go deeper. I found that method `builder.ConfigureTestServices()` overrides other services. But when switch this in my `ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)` method and I try to create new HttpClient using `CreateClient()` it throws:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'A ConfigureServices method that returns an IServiceProvider is not compatible with the use of one or more IStartupConfigureServicesFilter. Use a void returning ConfigureServices method instead or a ConfigureContainer method.'
```

@Update 28.05.2019

**Still looking for better solution**, but I've manage to do sort of *hack*.

In my `Startup.cs` I've swapped my

`services.AddScoped<IEmailProvider, SendGridEmailProvider>();`

with TryAdd[Something]

`services.TryAddScoped<IEmailProvider, SendGridEmailProvider>();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to do it in the ConfigureWebHost similar to the below:

```
public class CustomWebApplicationFactory : WebApplicationFactory<Startup>
{
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder) 
    {
        builder.ConfigureServices(services => 
        {
            // Remove application IEmailProvider service
            var emailProviderDescriptor = services.SingleOrDefault(d => d.ServiceType == typeof(IEmailProvider));
            if (emailProviderDescriptor != null)
            {
                services.Remove(emailProviderDescriptor);
            }

            // Add new test service(s)
            services.AddScoped<IEmailProvider, TestEmailProvider>();
            services.AddSingleton<TestEmailServer>(); // May need to remove using the descriptor similar to IEmailProvider

            // Remove the app's GrabGoContext registration, add in memory one then seed data.
            var dbDescriptor = services.SingleOrDefault(d => d.ServiceType == typeof(DbContextOptions<GrabGoContext>));
            if (dbDescriptor != null)
            {
                services.Remove(dbDescriptor);
            }

            services.AddDbContext<GrabGoContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseInMemoryDatabase("InMemoryDbForTesting");
            });

            var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
            using var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope();
            var scopedServices = scope.ServiceProvider;
            var grabGoContext = scopedServices.GetRequiredService<GrabGoContext>();

            // Seed your db here & save..
            grabGoContext.SaveChanges();
        });

        base.ConfigureWebHost(builder);
    }
}
```

You may want to make it easier on yourself and just implement the factory, like the above, rather than keep it generic. I've also added slightly different code for your in-memory database.

It hasn't been compiled, but the syntax shouldn't be far off. 
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

I just spent several hours trying to do a similar thing (override the services in my integration tests).   Turns out `ConfigureServices` runs *before* the SUT (subject under test) service configuration.   `ConfigureTestServices`, however, runs *after* and is where you would override with your mocks.

The docs are not at all clear on this, though I did, after the fact, find this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-3.0#inject-mock-services

Answer (score 1):

You can do it based on Environment.  This is just code to point you in the right direction.

```
  public IHostingEnvironment HostingEnvironment { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        if (HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            services.AddTransient<ITestService, TestService>();
        }
        else
        {
            services.AddTransient<IRealService, RealService>();
        }

        // other services
    }
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I thouht of that, but I don't want to mess real code with my test code.

Comment: So what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to change default app behavior (maybe override it) to make it suitable for integration tests. But I shouldn't have any test related things in my app codebase.

Comment: Ohh... It looks like a solution, kinda. Thanks, but I'm looking for the more smooth thing. If I don't find any. I'll probably use your idea :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try calling **ConfigureTestServices** instead of **ConfigureServices**:

```
protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
{
    builder
        .UseEnvironment("Test")
        .ConfigureTestServices(services =>
        {
           // Put your logic here
        }); ;
}
```